# Перезапуск курсора

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, курсор

Подскажите, можно ли заставить курсор вернуться сразу на первую запись после завершения и выполнить опять полный проход от начала и до конца?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью команды `FETCH FIRST`. Для этого курсор должен быть объявлен с опцией `SCROLL`.

Пример:

```
declare @table table (ID int);
insert into @table values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

declare cs cursor local scroll
    for select ID from @table order by checksum(newid());

declare @id int;
open cs;

declare @pass int = 1, @maxPass int = 2;
while 1 = 1
begin
    fetch next from cs into @id;

    if @@fetch_status != 0
    begin
        if @pass < @maxPass
        begin
            set @pass += 1;
            -- перемещаемся в начало, если нужен ещё один проход:
            fetch first from cs into @id;
            -- вариант, если нужно переоткрыть курсор:
            --close cs;
            --open cs;
            --fetch next from cs into @id;
        end;
        else  -- иначе завершение
            break;
    end;

    print @id;
end;

close cs;
deallocate cs;
```

Вместо перемещения в начало можно также переоткрывать курсор парой команд `CLOSE` и `OPEN`, тогда опция `SCROLL` не понадобится. При этом, однако, следует учитывать, что при закрытии курсора освобождаются блокировки, которые могли быть установлены при использовании курсора, что не всегда желательно. Т.е. `CLOSE` + `OPEN` не эквивалентно `FETCH FIRST` полностью.

Comment: А при CLOSe+OPEN запросы на наполнение курсора выполнится повторно? У меня там просто хитрая сортировка, которая сортирует записи случайным образом и я бы хотел каждый новый цикл получать новый набор.

Comment: @iluxa1810, да, при переоткрытии курсора запрос перевыполнится заново, и при случайной сортировке порядок будет новый. При смещении в начало с помощью `fetch first` порядок сохранится, т.к. запрос перевыполнен не будет.